# Deploy ExtJS on RHEL server

Tags: linux, extjs, deployment, build

I am looking for the best practices for deploying an ExtJS app on a RHEL server. I tried installing sencha CMD on the server so that I could do the application build there, but I kept getting a segmentation fault with the 64-bit version and nothing happened with the 32-bit version (both as a normal user and with sudo). I even tried ssh'ing in with a -X option to enable Xterm, but that did not work. I am thinking I am going to have to do an external build and then deploy the entire contents to the server.

Ultimately, I would be doing this through a Bamboo server (same as Jenkins). For testing purposes though, I am going to use Webstorm. Anything I should be aware of/watch out for? I am deploying the entire project directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright: I was able to do this as root. Interesting. I should now be able to set up my Bamboo process.